# Windows 10 icons appearance changed

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop-customization

A cat slept on the keyboard and all my desktop icons are now looking like in the picture : Three lines of text description to the right of the image. How can I fix it to see the normal behavior ( **one line below the picture**) ?

[image]

Edit: Ctrl + Mouse Wheel doesn't help

Comment: If a malicious cat is allowed to sleep on the keyboard, it's not your computer anymore ;)

Comment: +1 for identifying "a cat slept on the keyboard" as cause of the problem.

Comment: I am debating if I should tag this with [tag:cat]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I keep my cat off my keyboard](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/how-can-i-keep-my-cat-off-my-keyboard)... :P

Comment: @angussidney Probably should say "related"? Actually I didn't know this lifehacks stackexchange existed and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I'm not sure how your cat managed it, as the keyboard shortcut to do this is `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `8` I believe.

However, to put it back to normal, right click anywhere on the desktop, click `view`, followed by any option, EG `Medium Icons`.

EDIT: As there has been some interest, `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `number` produces different views when used on any folder, including the Windows Desktop.

1. Extra Large Icons
2. Large Icons
3. Medium Icons
4. Small Icons
5. List View
6. Details
7. Tiles
8. Content

Tested working in Windows 10, Windows 8.1 and Windows Servers 2012 and 2016 (Hotkey may vary between editions, as it's reported to be `Ctrl` + `Alt` on Windows Server 2016 TP4 (Simplified Chinese))

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that you can have detailed view in the desktop (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`6` in my Windows 10)!

Comment: windows 7 doesn't seem to support this

Comment: I didn't know either! Awesome. +1 because I learned something new.

Comment: Have updated my answer with your findings, thanks.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`8` on my Windows Server 2016 TP4 (Simplified Chinese)

Comment: Never underestimate what a cat can do to your equipment.  My father's cat managed to remove some keys from the laptop's keyboard.