# Scrollbar on the right of my desktop

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop, scrollbar

After reading [this](https://superuser.com/q/1021484/516846) post I was trying out the crtl+shift+number sequences.

Now I have a scrollbar on the right of my screen (even with smallest icons selected).

How can I remove the scrollbar now?

[image: Desktop with scrollbar to the right]

Comment: screenshot please?

Comment: This sometimes happens - you can reboot the machine, or you can end the `explorer.exe` process in task manager, then go to `File` -> `Run new task` -> `explorer.exe` to restart it.

Comment: @Jonno great solution! Place it as an answer and I will accept. I also discovered explorer.exe now has a restart option. So I didn't have to stop it and start it again as we used to with `File -> Run new task -> explorer.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sometimes happens, a strange bug in treating the desktop as a normal desktop window.

To fix this, you can either reboot the machine, or you can end the `explorer.exe` process in task manager, then go to `File` -> `Run new task` -> `explorer.exe` to restart it.

Windows 8, 8.1 and 10 now have an option to **restart** `explorer.exe` from the task manager also.

[image: Windows Restart Image]

Comment: `WIN` + `R` > `tskill explorer` - It should automatically restart by itself.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases restarting explorer.exe is an undesirable solution.  This can be solved (arduously) by using Themes to remove the special desktop icons (My Computer, Network, etc.) then cut and paste everything from the desktop into a folder.  Do Ctrl+Shift+6 to shift the desktop into file explorer mode; right-click on the desktop and choose medium or large icons.  Some people say your Zoom must be set to 100% as well.  The scrollbar should vanish so you can repopulate your desktop with the saved items again.
Ctrl+Shift+(number) now have dramatic effects on the way desktops are displayed.